# Problems installing emacs ESS using make

Tags: r, makefile, emacs, ess

I am trying to install emacs ESS using GNU make.
i follow the installation instructions  for ESS found in the following
link:

steps 2 and 3 :

http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Installation

for each step i get errors when using make:
below are the instructions and the error messages for each step:

**First Instruction:**

2. Optionally, compile elisp files and build the documentation with: 
   cd /path/to/ESS/
   make
   Without this step, info, pdf and html documentation and reference card will not be available.

**My Action:**

```
C:\Program Files\ESS\ess-17.11>make
```

**System Messages:**

```
cd etc; make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ESS/ess-17.11/etc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ESS/ess-17.11/etc'
cd lisp; make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ESS/ess-17.11/lisp'
emacs -batch -no-site-file -no-init-file -l ./ess-comp.el -f batch-byte-compile ess-custom.el
emacs: not found
make[1]:  [ess-custom.elc] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ESS/ess-17.11/lisp'
make:  [all] Error 2
```

**Second Instruction:**

3. Optionally, install into your local machine with make install. You might need administrative privileges: 
   make install
   The files are installed into /usr/share/emacs directory. For this step to run correctly on macOS, you will need to adjust the PREFIX path in Makeconf. The necessary code and instructions are commented in that file.

**My Action:**

```
C:\Program Files\ESS\ess-17.11>make install
```

**System Messages:**

```
cd etc; make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ESS/ess-17.11/etc'
mkdir -p /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/icons
mkdir -p /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/ESSR/R
cp -p .IS.RELEASE git-ref *.S sas-keys.* ess-sas-sh-command *.jl /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess
cp -p icons/*.xpm /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/icons
cp -p ESSR/LOADREMOTE ESSR/VERSION /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/ESSR
cp -p ESSR/R/*.R ESSR/R/.*.R /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/ESSR/R
chmod +x /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/ess-sas-sh-command
chmod: not found
make[1]: *** [install] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ESS/ess-17.11/etc'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I'll appreciate you help with installing ESS using make.

Thanks
Rafael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute under Windows commands, which are for Linux environments.
Specifically, your installation fails at the following lines:

```
emacs -batch -no-site-file -no-init-file -l ./ess-comp.el -f batch-byte-compile ess-custom.el
emacs: not found
```

and

```
chmod +x /usr/share/emacs/etc/ess/ess-sas-sh-command
chmod: not found
```

There is no `chmod` command under Windows. Here is the cmd equivalent: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/windows-change-access-permissions-from-the-command-line.html

The ESS Manual you provided suggests the following approach:

> Note for Windows and macOS users: The most straightforward way to
>   install Emacs on your machine is by downloading the Emacs binary by
>   Vincent Goulet; either Emacs Modified for macOS or from [Emacs Modified
>   for Windows.](https://vigou3.github.io/emacs-modified-windows/)

I also suggest that you install the [Emacs Modified for Windows](https://vigou3.github.io/emacs-modified-windows/), as installation via make under windows will be too difficult/costly - virtually impossible.

Comment: The reason i thought to use "make" is to keep up with the latest versions of emacs and ess. especially due to the fact that i have a 32 bit machine and that the modified emacs+ess version for the 32 bit version is not the latest. Anyway it seems that you are right that using the modified version is simpler and more practical. Thanks